# A quantum entanglement experiment

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, measurements, faster-than-light

Suppose we have an entangled electron-positron pair, such that total spin is zero. Separate them, and let Alice measure the spin (along $z$) of the electron, obtaining, say, $+\frac{1}{2}$. All the subsequent measurements of this will give the same ($+\frac{1}{2}$) result (supposing the positron is still untouched). Now, afterwards, on the other end Robert measures the spin of the positron along $y$-axis, which will negate the result of the first measurement, so that if Alice measures the electron's spin along $z$ again, she will have 50% chance to get $+\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2}$. If it is $+\frac{1}{2}$ she doesn't get any new information, but, if she obtains $-\frac{1}{2}$, she will *immediately* know that a measurement has been made at Robert's side: instantaneous communication has been performed. So, what is wrong with this thought experiment?

Comment: If robert measures the spin on the y direction he will get a 50% chance. Plus once Alice makes the first measurement the particles are no longer entangled, whatever Bob measures does not affect the state of Alice's patrticle .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose we have an entangled electron-positron pair, such that total spin is zero. Separate them, and let Alice measure the spin (along zz) of the electron, obtaining, say, +1/2,+1/2. All the subsequent measurements of this will give the same (+1/2,+1/2) result (supposing the positron is still untouched).

All of the subsequent measurements will give the same result regardless of what has happened to the positron. Nothing that happens to the positron has any effect at all on the electron until and unless information about what happened propagates to the electron:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007.

> Now, afterwards, on the other end Robert measures the spin of the positron along y-axis, which will negate the result of the first measurement, so that if Alice measures the electron's spin along zz again, she will have 50% chance to get +1/2,+1/2 or −1/2,−1/2.

Another measurement doesn't undo the effect of the first measurement. The only thing that would undo the first measurement is actually undoing the measurement: transferring all of the information about the system in the outside world back into the measured system.